# Difference response for difference request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, request, response

I'm a newbie in NodeJS and ExpressJS framework. I'm not sure about this thing: If the system receive many requests then server return many difference responses for those users, right? So they're not affect each other, right?

Example:I set language for request of user 1 in response.locals.language = 'english' then for user 2 is response.locals.language = 'vietnamese' on 2 separate browsers. If I refresh user 1 page so is language of user 2 change from vietnamese to english?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If I refresh user 1 page so is language of user 2 change from vietnamese to english?`
 
they're not affect each other no matter what request received

Answer (score 0):

Every request gets its own `request` and `response` object, that is separate from other requests.

See the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), specifically:

- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req
- http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Those object are passed as arguments to your handler. It's like a normal function that gets fresh arguments on every invocation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way will you get same request and response objects. They are not inter related.